# Get element by id

Tags: javascript, html

So I have made an table which is created automatically by JS and it gives each td tag an ID by

```
id='("+x+","+y+")'
```

as the x is table-row and y is table-data

How can I call this ID in other function with getElementById attribute?

Comment: It doesn't look like your quotes are right.

Comment: `id='("' + x + '","' + y + '")'` or better `\`$id=("${x}", "${y}")\``

Comment: Can't you use a couple of nth-child CSS selectors instead of assigning IDs to each cell?  `#myTable tr:nth-child(x + 1) td:nth-child(y + 1)` or similar?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotes look wrong, it should be:

```
id='('+x+','+y+')'
```

Then you should be able to use

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

If `x = 12` and `y = 57` this will match `id="(12,57)"`.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you can use ES6 you can write it as follows:

```js
const 
  x = 4,
  y = 9,
  id = `(${x},${y})`;
  
console.log(`The ID is "${id}"`);
```

I personally find this much easier to read.